# How to download files from s3 latest files to local folder using powerShell script and need to include file corruption check point

Tags: powershell, aws-powershell

I need to download latest files from AWS S3 bucket using powershell script and as well as how can tackle file corruption while downloading.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What file corruption are you talking about?

Comment: I Have tried below version It's download and replace the all file from s3 to local.But I required only latest/Modified files only also how can check downloaded file is not corrupted(If In case large files).